# IntentReciever leak on orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, resource-leak

I have registered `SMS_RECIEVED` `broadcastreceiver` in CustomWebView. I've taken care of registering and unregistering of receiver on activity's life cycle. All works well until orientation changes.

I've tried placing register/unregister reciever under different states of webview like `onAttachedToWindow()`/`onDetachedFromWindow()`, `onPause()`/`onResume()`(explicitly calling from activity's `onPause()`/`onResume()`), `onStart()`/`onStop()`. But nothing seems to prevent `IntentReceiver` leak on orientation change.

Here's the code i've tried:

**CustomWebView.java**

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    BroadcastReceiver reciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                try {
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        Log.v(tag, "Got PDUS Obj [" + pdusObj + "]");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(tag, "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
                }
            }
        };

    --------------------
    --------------------
    some code
    --------------------

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        try {
            IntentFilter intents = new IntentFilter(
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            getContext().registerReceiver(reciver, intents);
            Log.i(tag, "Webview sms reciever registered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        try {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(reciver);
            Log.i(tag, "Webview sms reciever unregistered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }



    // Tried this one too
    /* @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Log.i(tag, "Billdesk onAttach to window called");
        try {
            IntentFilter intents = new IntentFilter(
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            getContext().registerReceiver(reciver, intents);
            Log.i(tag, "Webview sms reciever registered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        Log.i(tag, "Billdesk onDetach From window to window called");
        try {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(reciver);
            Log.i(tag, "Webview sms reciever unregistered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } */

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

-----------
-----------
-----------

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (this.customWebView != null)
            this.customWebView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (this.customWebView != null)
            this.customWebView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

I get following error when, orientation is changed :

```
Activity com.abcd.xyz.ActivityClass has leaked IntentReceiver com.abcd.xyz.CustomWebView$2@4898758 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: Why don't you create methods like registerReceiver/unregisterReceiver in CustomWebView and then call it from parent onResume/onPause ... also is the CustomWebView  part of the Activity's layout or Fragment layout?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm getting the error while calling getContext().registerReceiver(reciver, intents); on CustomWebView after orientation change

Comment: @Selvin I've tried that too. But didn't got the problem solved. CustomWebView is part of fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur due to device screen rotation...

When the phone rotates and the screen changes orientation, Android usually destroys your application’s existing Activities and Fragments and recreates them. Android does this so that your application can reload resources based on the new configuration.

And your receiver was register on activity's last  object or instance. So the solution is save the receiver object...

You can save any Object by Overriding public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance () and calling getLastNonConfigurationInstance() in your onCreate method.

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
// Save the reciever obj here

return data;
}

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

Hope this help you.